# AngularJs NgRoute

Tags: javascript

For some reason my ngRoute dosent work properly? I dont know but it dosent show any error on the console either. **[Here](https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/fourm#openfile-README.md)** is my Cloud9 File. And here is my script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('ChattApp', ["firebase", "ngRoute"])

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'HtmlFiles/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
      })

      .when('/Register', {
        templateUrl: 'HtmlFiles/registration.html',
        controller: 'RegistrationController'
      })

      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });


  });


app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://uniquecoders.firebaseio.com/");
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not injecting the $routeProvider into the config function.

Take a look at the tutorial for the $routeProvider [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07#the-app-module) or take not of the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Thats why i struggle with this a lot. Thank you so much sir!! Your the best!

Comment: Did that but same problem :( https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/fourm#openfile-README.md        I have to go to school now. Would love if you can fix! Thankyou!

Comment: The only bad things I saw were missing semi-colons and that the could9 editor doesn't know what angular and firebase are as variables because it can't see them until browser execution

Comment: Wait whitch ones exactly? Thankyou

Comment: Ignore that last bit, I'm too used to using build tools. Anyway, line 1 and 13 are missing semi-colons. If you can run this script on your laptop instead of in the cloud, I'd suggest getting npm so you can use tools like [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and [JSHint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint) to help you build it all up. You can easily use these on the command line and run them using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)